# Google Maps Streetview - How to get Panorama ID

Tags: google-maps

I want to use custom panorama position, but I need a panorama id for it. Can someone explain me how to get the panorama id from the next link:

https://www.google.nl/maps/@52.239981,6.851849,3a,90y,324.71h,64.65t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sFEpIJhSgOzoAAAQJOQCL3w!2e0!3e11

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate or similar question. I have posted a solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523173/google-maps-embed-api-panorama-id/41100453#41100453

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it!

https://www.google.nl/maps/@52.239981,6.851849,3a,90y,324.71h,64.65t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sFEpIJhSgOzoAAAQJOQCL3w!2e0!3e11

After the !1s and before the !2e is the Panorama ID, so here is it:

FEpIJhSgOzoAAAQJOQCL3w

Comment: as per you answer i get panorama id:  F:-pMnNjSor9eU/VlPYTVL0MeI/AAAAAAAAR0U/DDixeQie1Jo  but when i set it to streetViewPanorama its not loading.it show black screen ,can you please help me?

Answer (score 13):

Google changed the format of the pano IDs with their updates in Aug/Sept. Similar to before the pano ID can be found between the !1s and !2e. So in the example posted by Jason the pano ID would be (urldecoded):

`F:-gVtvWrACv2k/Vnh0Vg8Z8YI/AAAAAAABLWA/a-AT4Wb8MD8`

In order to get it to work for us we had to prepend the F: in front of it. There is also a known bug which requires the addition of an undocumented flag to use newer panos (see https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7452#c51):

```js
google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
```

Answer (score 6):

This does not work for photos added to Google Maps after the Sept 3rd 2015 update.

https://www.google.com/maps/@28.4184117,-80.6076033,3a,75y,349h,88t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-gVtvWrACv2k%2FVnh0Vg8Z8YI%2FAAAAAAABLWA%2Fa-AT4Wb8MD8!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-gVtvWrACv2k%2FVnh0Vg8Z8YI%2FAAAAAAABLWA%2Fa-AT4Wb8MD8%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i11000!8i5500

Comment: so what we have to do?

Answer (score 6):

1. Find the pano on Google Maps
2. Open Developer Tools console
3. Copy/Paste/Run the following. Result should be the pano id.

```html
"F:".concat(window.location.href.split("!1s")[1].split("!2e")[0]).replace('%2F','/')
```

Thanks @Rgrauphics

Comment: This will only replace the first %2F. If you want to replace all, you have to replace it with Regex: 
`"F:".concat(window.location.href.split("!1s")[1].split("!2e")[0]).replace(/%2F/g,'/')`

Answer (score 3):

As Justin MacLeod mentioned, but here is what I did exactly.

You need to adjust the ID number. You can still find the ID number between the !1s and !2e but you need to update your url for it to work.

```
Add F: to the start of your ID
Change %2F in the ID to /
```

My ID example
Before:

```
-3_7tAKLhLLU%2FV0nuKmxj7xI%2FAAAAAAAAdE8%2FHZYhfYoBGqAsQw-63snzF9OkIy7YT051ACLIB
```

After:

```
F:-3_7tAKLhLLU/V0nuKmxj7xI/AAAAAAAAdE8/HZYhfYoBGqAsQw-63snzF9OkIy7YT051ACLIB
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a panorama ID (pano), I have developed a little HTML page whith which you can get some of its parameters (zoom/Pov, pitch and heading) and get the Street View Image request  HTTP URL.

*Don't forget to replace the **YOUR_API_KEY** with your own API key (obvious)*

Have fun with google maps!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 95%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #map,
    #pano {
        float: left;
        height: 95%;
        width: 45%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="tray">
    <button id="doer" onclick="doThings()">do it</button>
    <span id="resulting"></span>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<script>
    var panorama, map;
    var APIkey= "YOUR_API_KEY"

    function initialize() {
        var fenway = {
            lat: 42.345573,
            lng: -71.098326
        };
        var agbar = new google.maps.LatLng(41.4035482, 2.1894355);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: agbar,
            zoom: 14
        });
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('pano'), {
                position: agbar,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            });
        map.setStreetView(panorama);
    }

    function doThings() {
        console.log("doing things");
        document.getElementById("resulting").innerHTML = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640" +"&pano=" + panorama.getPano() + "&heading=" + panorama.getPov().heading + "&pitch=" + panorama.getPov().pitch + "&fov="+ (180/ (Math.pow(2, panorama.getZoom()?panorama.getZoom():1)))+ "&key=" + APIkey;
      //use the next line to open in a new tab the resulting image at max size (640x640)
        window.open("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x640" + "&pano=" + panorama.getPano() + "&heading=" + panorama.getPov().heading + "&pitch=" + panorama.getPov().pitch + "&fov="+ (180/ (Math.pow(2, panorama.getZoom())))+ "&key=" +APIkey)
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize">
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

*Instructions: create an html file, copy the code , replace API key, open html file in browser, push the "do it" button.*

More references can be found at Google's:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas

Answer (score 0):

When you're on google maps, looking at your interior panorama. Just click on the flag, to report the panorama. Then you'll see a parameter in the URL called 'panoid' with the panorama ID in it. You can just copy it there. It's not anywhere in the URL on the panorama page view itself anymore as far as I can see.

Comment: Seems not to be the case anymore

Comment: The pano id is not in the panoid parameter anymore but between '!2s' and '&' in the report page url. Should be 22 characters long. Still the easiest way by far to obtain the pano id from a panorama page with a couple of clicks and no programming. Just to clarify, you don't actually report a perfectly good panorama, you simply open the report form to get the id, then you close the form without submitting it. PS All other replies seem to be obsolete.