# How to Get Pano ID of particular location?

Tags: android

I want to show panorama view of particular location.when is search google for particular location then its give [url](https://www.google.co.in/maps/@25.222424,55.2583756,3a,75y,16.08h,81.79t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sLjE8i1tg1rEAAAQz-Qhs6Q!2e0!3e2!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DLjE8i1tg1rEAAAQz-Qhs6Q%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D32.352291%26pitch%3D0!7i8796!8i4398?hl=en) that url show panorama view,but i have to display it android so how I get pano Id of this location.

for this i have refer these solution:
[Google Maps Streetview - How to get Panorama ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916149/google-maps-streetview-how-to-get-panorama-id)
but its not working in my case.

Comment: Explain "it's not working"? What results do you get? Have you stepped through and checked the values to see if the URL format has changed?

Comment: when i refer the answer then i get solution that :
After the !1s and before the !2e is the Panorama ID.so i get                              F:-gVtvWrACv2k/Vnh0Vg8Z8YI/AAAAAAABLWA/a-AT4Wb8MD8 like that.but when i set this the panoroma view show black screen.