# GPS coordinates to display google street view panorama

Tags: gps, google-street-view

I looked at the documentation and many other questions but I couldn't find something similar to what I am looking for. I want a query url where I give in a gps coordinate and it displays the google street view panorama, or some kind of call that when I give it a GPS coordinate it gives me the "Panoid".

I dont have the panoid, or am I trying to extract it from a URL, I want to create a call that return the panoid.

Comment: You mean you want the FULL 360 panorama image? When you mean "display", you mean display in browser?

Comment: Display in the browser, if there is an option to download the tiles, which is what I am aiming at then that would be perfect, but I dont think this is possible. I already have a downloader from panoid, and I would like to do the same with GPS coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps Streetview - How to get Panorama ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916149/google-maps-streetview-how-to-get-panorama-id)

Comment: @heltonbiker That's totally different, I dont have the panoid to be able to extract from the url. Im trying to find the panoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that I actually wasnt looking for since Im writing my program in C++. But it seems I will do it in Javascript, and pass it to my C++ program.

In the Street View Api Documentation there is this example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service

In this example there are a few lines that are important to answering this question:

```
        var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
        // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
        panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
```

I could just grab the data.location.pano value from there, then use it as however I may like. I hope this is not a final answer, I really wish if there is another way where I dont have to create a webservice.

Answer (score -2):

What about this (via [Google Maps Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview))

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?
    size=10000x10000
    &location=46.414382,10.013988
    &heading=151.78
    &pitch=0
```

[image]