# I want to download Google street view panoramas in bulk, how I can obtain pano_id?

Tags: python

I have applied API key to download Google street view panoramas in bulk, how I can obtain pano_id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps Streetview - How to get Panorama ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916149/google-maps-streetview-how-to-get-panorama-id)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `google_streetview.api`

Example:

```
# Import google_streetview for the api module
import google_streetview.api

# Define parameters for street view api
params = [{
    'location': '33.89501412708861, 35.50698614535169',
    'size': '640x640', # max 640x640 pixels
    'heading': '360', # camera angle
    'pitch': '-0.76',
    'key': google_dev_key
}]

# Create a results object
results = google_streetview.api.results(params)

results.save_metadata('metadata.json')
results.download_links('downloads')
```

you can get your google_dev_key from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/credentials)